# javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /my.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The prefix "f" for element "f:facet" is not bound

Tags: jsf, facelets, xml-namespaces, prefix

I would like to create table which can display data from database into JSF page. I found this code:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bookStore.items}" var="store">
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText  value="#{msg.storeNameLabel}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{store.name}"/>
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      Subject
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{store.subject}"/>
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText  value="#{msg.storePriceLabel}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{store.price}"/>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

When I use this code I get this error message in Netbeans:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /my.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The prefix "f" for element "f:facet" is not bound

If I replace the `f` tag with `h` tag, is it going to work? Or do I have to include `f` tag library?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to inlude the correct taglib for the f prefix.

Here is an example for a JSF 2.2 Facelet page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

...
</html>
```

In case you're still on JSF 2.0/2.1, use `java.sun.com` domain instead of `xmlns.jcp.org` domain in XML namespace.

I recommend to read a JSF tutorial, you can find links in [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the `f` with `h` won't work, since there's no `h:facet` (in the JSF html taglib which is likely to be assigned to the `h` prefix). You'll have to include the appropriate taglib (JSF core) and assign it to the `f` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Include taglib. `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>`

Comment: Seems not the be the jsf way of doing it